# Use multiple ORBs through different threads (multithreaded multi-orb client application) - how?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, corba, orbacus

<sub>This question is related to: [**Is it possible to have several ORB objects in the same process?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933790/is-it-possible-to-have-several-orb-objects-in-the-same-process)</sub>

So, thanks to @BrianKelly I found information about the `ORB` identifier (even though there was no such information in all `ORBACUS` docs, that I have) and I successfully created a simple application, that connects to different `CORBA` servers and successfully executed several `CORBA` requests.

So far, so good.

Now, what I want to do, is to make this application multithreaded and to start a separate thread for the connection to the different servers. But `ORB_init` crashes.

Here's a very short code, that I use for testing:

```
#include <OB/CORBA.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void* run( void * );

struct config { const char* nameservice; const char* id; const char* exe; };

const bool mt = true;

int main()
{
    config cfg1 = { "NameService=corbaloc::10.102.8.15:13069/NameService", "1", "test" };
    config cfg2 = { "NameService=corbaloc::192.168.1.99:13069/NameService", "2", "test" };

    if( mt )
    {   
        pthread_t t1, t2;

        pthread_create( &t1, NULL, run, (void*)&cfg1 ); 
        pthread_create( &t2, NULL, run, (void*)&cfg2 ); 

        pthread_join( t1, NULL ); pthread_join( t2, NULL );
    }
    else
    {
        run( (void*)&cfg1 );
        run( (void*)&cfg2 );
    }

    printf( "SUCCESS!\n" );
    return 0;
}

void* run( void* arg )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

    int argc = 2; char* argv[3];

    config* cfg = (config*)arg;
    argv[0] = (char*)cfg->exe;
    argv[1] = (char*)cfg->nameservice;
    argv[2] = NULL;

    CORBA::ORB_var m_varOrb = CORBA::ORB_init( argc, argv, cfg->id );

    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
    return NULL;
}
```

So, when `mt` is `false`, everything's fine, I can extend the code to create some server specific objects, to execute different requests, etc. But then `mt` is `true`, the second thread fails calling `ORB_init`. See the stack trace below.

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something very simple and stupid, but what?

```
$ g++ -g3 -ggdb -Wall -Wshadow -march=i486 
      -DUNIX -DLINUX -DPTHREADS -DMULTITHREAD -D_REENTRANT
      -I. -I/usr/local/include/OB/ -I/usr/local/include/JTC/ 
      -I/usr/include/OB/ -I/usr/include/JTC/ -L/usr/local/lib 
      -lpthread -lm -lz -lrt -ldl -lOB -lJTC -lCosNaming 
      test.cpp
```

Stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00566402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x0080dfd0 in raise () from /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
#2  0x0080f9b1 in abort () from /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
#3  0x03dc490b in ~RefCount 
    (this=Could not find the frame base for "~RefCount".) 
    at ../../include/OB/RefCount_Ts_Linux-x86-32.h:43
#4  0x03ef8965 in ORBInstance 
    (this=Could not find the frame base for "ORBInstance".) 
    at ORBInstance.cpp:276
#5  0x03f134fe in ORB_impl 
    (this=Could not find the frame base for "ORB_impl".) 
    at ORB_impl.cpp:281
#6  0x03f24740 in OBCORBA::ORB_init 
    (ac=Could not find the frame base for 
        "OBCORBA::ORB_init(int&, char**, OB::Properties*, 
                           OB::Logger*, OB::Reactor*, 
                           char const*, char const*)". ) 
    at ORB_init.cpp:994
#7  0x03f249d9 in CORBA::ORB_init 
    (ac=Could not find the frame base for 
         "CORBA::ORB_init(int&, char**, char const*, char const*)".) 
    at ORB_init.cpp:1014
#8  0x0804895d in run (arg=0xbfe8b544) at test_server.cpp:45
#9  0x007334d2 in start_thread () from /lib/i686/nosegneg/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x008b848e in clone () from /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
```

Comment: At the end of your thread function try calling `m_varOrb->shutdown(true)` followed by `m_VarOrb->destroy()`. That way the ORB will get cleaned up before the `_var` goes out of scope and cleans up what it's pointing to.

Comment: You might also want to read Ciaran McHale's excellent guide to CORBA here: http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/

Comment: @BrianKelly - well, this is a tiny example, reproducing my issue, not the real code. Actually, the `run` function is a member of a class, deriving class wrapper for threads, there's a `while( m_bRunning )` loop inside and all threads (usually 4) should be able to work in the same time. So, executing `shutdown` and `destroy` at the end of this `run` are not options (they _are_ executed in a `DoDisconnect` method, but this is something else.

Comment: @BrianKelly - thanks for the tutorial, I'll take a look at it, I've looked at a lot of tutorials, user manuals, books (including _Advanced CORBA Programming_), etc. I've never seen anything about such environment, what I want to make.

Comment: My point is that the lack of `shutdown` and `destroy` in your test case might be what's causing the crash.

Comment: @BrianKelly - the crash is in `ORB_init`, I can't execute `shutdown` and/or `destroy` before the second init, as I want all threads to work in parallel.

Comment: Ah, well I couldn't see the whole stack trace. You should post that too.

Comment: @BrianKelly - I added the stack trace.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the ORB. What's about their support?

Comment: Does your code works with only one ORB instance? I cannot believe it does.

Comment: @tuergeist - what do you mean exactly? It works fine with one ORB and one thread. It works fine with one orb, shared between several threads. But this means (for now) - only one server. I found something like workaround and I'll write it here, when I test it good.

Comment: Why don't you consult your ORB vendor and see if instantiating multiple ORBs in one application is possible? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @BrianNeal - it is possible. The question is - how exactly? I don't think I need to contact the ORB vendor for such thing. And I doubt this deserves down-vote.

Comment: How do you know it is possible? I suspect most ORBs are not designed to have multiple instances running in the same address space. More importantly, why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish that you think cannot be done with only a single ORB instance?

Comment: @BrianNeal - why I think it works - see my example, when `mt == false`. Why not using a single ORB instance - because till yesterday, I thought it's not possible to use a single ORB instance to connect to different servers, but I found out, that I can use `ORBInitRef` multiple times, so this should do the work. But makes my code uglier. And as in a single thread I can create more than one ORB, there must be a way to make this through different threads. Don't you think?

Comment: It is ORB dependent behavior. I suspect most ORB's are not designed to have multiple threads calling ORB_init() at the same time from different threads. You could try bracketing your ORB_init() calls with a mutex or serialize your calls somehow to see if the crash stops.

Comment: @BrianNeal - see my example once again. There's such mutex (global), that's locked/unlocked, so that the threads are sync-ed (`ORB_init` is not called at the same time..)

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. I again maintain that what your are doing is not specified behavior in the CORBA spec, and it would depend on implementation details of your ORB. The ORBs I am familiar with actually do not even implement the 3rd argument (the ORB ID) to ORB_init(), and I am fairly certain they would crash if you called ORB_init() from multiple threads also. Good luck.

Comment: @BrianNeal - I agree with you. At the beginning, I thought that it's not possible and I almost gave it up. But as it works with a single thread (using the ORB id), there should be some way to make it work with more threads.. It just doesn't make sense (at least to me). Thanks for wishing me luck. If you think my question is reasonable, please revert your downvote (if it's yours, of course). It would take too long to explain why I actually need this, but it's reasonable and discussed with a several senior engineers, trust me :)

Comment: @KirilKirov What do you mean with "But this means (for now) - only one server." - You do not need more than one ORB instance. It doesn't make sense.  Please describe more detailed your real problem. I feel that you think that multiple ORBs solve your problem, but it may not.

Comment: @tuergeist - my "real problem" is - I want **different threads for the different connections to different servers**. I thought, that the only possible way to do this is to have several ORBs. Then I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009694/use-multiple-orbs-through-different-threads-multithreaded-multi-orb-client-appl/13089087#13089087 **where I received an answer how to create multiple ORBs**. Then the **new issue** was - **how to do this by different threads**, not by a single one. Having the answer of my previous question, I researched a little more and I found....

Comment: @tuergeist - ...out about "**multi-ORB applications**". That's why I posted this question. **Later**, it appeared, that there's another solution, which I **posted in my own answer below**. I think all of this is well described in my question+answer, but whatever. Is it clear enough now?

Comment: @KirilKirov The ORB will use different connections (and threads) to different servers every time - always. Receiving answers and incomming calls are also handled in different threads. I think you try try to solve things, that the ORB already ha solved for you. It's a middleware, don't scare about threading and stuff. It's already done by CORBA experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something like a workaround. Makes my code really ugly and not easy for support, but it's still something.

Here's what I did:

- add a mechanism (in my application), that will count the necessary threads, before starting them
- read, in advance, the configurations - I need to know the necessary parameters for the naming services (used in `ORB_init`)
- before starting any threads, a "manager" will execute **just once** `ORB_init`, but it will pass **several** times the `-ORBInitRef` parameter, with different values - one for each thread/connection
- after this is done, the threads are started, but instead of executing `ORB_init`, they directly execute `resolve_initial_references` and continue with the server specific things

Note: My example does not containt `resolve_initial_references`, because the crash is in `ORB_init`.

---

So, applying this "algorithm" for this "workaround" would look like:

```
#include <OB/CORBA.h>

void* run( void * );
CORBA::ORB_var varORB;

int main()
{
    /** The necessary configurations */
    //-------------------------------------v
    const char* nameservice1 = "NameService1=corbaloc::10.102.8.15:13069/NameService";
    const char* nameservice2 = "NameService2=corbaloc::192.168.1.99:13069/NameService";
    //-------------------------------------^

    /** INIT the ORB **/
    int argc = 5; char* argv[ 6 ];
    const char* initref = "-ORBInitRef";
    const char* exe = "test";

    argv[0] = (char*)exe;
    argv[1] = (char*)initref; argv[2] = (char*)nameservice1;
    argv[3] = (char*)initref; argv[4] = (char*)nameservice2;
    argv[5] = NULL;

    varORB = CORBA::ORB_init( argc, argv );

    pthread_t t1, t2; 

    char ns_id1 = '1', ns_id2 = '2';
    pthread_create( &t1, NULL, run, (void*)&ns_id1 );  
    pthread_create( &t2, NULL, run, (void*)&ns_id2 );  

    pthread_join( t1, NULL ); pthread_join( t2, NULL );

    varORB->destroy();

    return 0;
}
void* run( void* arg )
{
    char nameservice[] = "NameServiceN";

    // set the right number of the nameservice
    nameservice[ 11 ] = *((char*)arg);  

    varORB->resolve_initial_references( nameservice );

    // do some CORBA-specific stuff

    printf( "SUCCESS %c\n", *(char*)arg );
    return NULL;
}
```

---

### NOTE

I still can't believe this is the only option. If you look at my code (in the question) carefully, you'll see, that:

- it **IS** possible to have multiple ORBs (see the case with `mt == false`)
- the call to `ORB_init` **IS** synchronized
- the ORB identifier **IS** implemented and it works fine (again with `mt == false`)

So, this is not actual answer to my question, it's kind of a workaround.

It doesn't make sense (at least to me) to be possible to create several ORBs in a single thread, but not in multiple threads.

Comment: If I really had a reason to call ORB_init() multiple times, this is the way I would do it. :) omniORB for example, assumes certain things about the thread that calls ORB_init(), so calling it again with another thread would likely confuse it. I suspect the same is true with your ORB.

Comment: Pffffft, fail! Even if the `ORB` object is `shutdown` and `destroy`-ed, it cannot be created by another thread! It can be initialized again **only by the first thread**, who invoked `ORB_init` at the very beginning. That's ridiculous! If I try to initialize it from another thread (after it's been destroyed), the crash is the same. I really can't believe this, dammit.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you want to call ORB_init multiple times. Is it because you need to contact different naming services? I'm not sure but I think you should be able initialize the orb once, then create an object reference to each naming service using orb.string_to_object() using some kind of URI to each naming service.

Answer (score 0):

The ORB will use different connections (and threads) to different servers every time - always. Receiving answers and incomming calls are also handled in different threads (if useful and/or needed).

I think you try try to solve things, that the ORB already has solved for you. It's a middleware, don't scare about threading and stuff. It's already done by CORBA experts.

Comment: OK, a little more about the whole application - I have a thread, that accepts requests from another application(**not CORBA**). This thread analyzes these requests and decides what to do with them. These requests must be rerouted to **one** of **several different** CORBA servers. In other words, this thread is kind of a manager, it **manages several threads, connected to different CORBA servers**. That's why I need to have different threads, which handle different connections to different CORBA servers in a single application.

Comment: This is the architecture of an application with 25 000+ rows of code, which works with different protocols (over 20). Here, the CORBA part is the protocol specific part. This is an architecture of a connector, used by an application, which must be able to communicate with any other applications, using any protocol. My point is - I can't change the architecture.

Comment: Yep, I get that. I was just explaining what and why I was trying to do.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty, as they will expire soon and because of your effort. Thanks, it's useful information but does not actually answer my question.

Comment: I'm really sorry that it doesn't fit your question nor it is what you expected to get.

Comment: Ah, no problem, of course. At this moment, I have a solution (my answer), I'm just curious why the case, described in my question, crashes. Thanks a lot for the help :)